# Converting "Yes" or "No" string to Boolean in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to convert a `"yes/no"`string to boolean in kotlin. My solution is defining an extension function on String class and do the yes no che in a when expression:

```kotlin
fun String.toBoolean(): Boolean {
    when (this.toUpperCase()) {
        "YES" -> return true
        "NO" -> return false
    }
    return false
}
```

Any other possible ways?

Comment: There is `fun String.toBoolean() = when(this.toUpperCase()) { "YES" -> true; else -> false }` though same efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the default case is `false` this could be simplified:

```
fun String.toBoolean() = equals("YES", ignoreCase = true)
```

To simplify this we are depending on the fact that anything that isn't "yes" will be false. We also tell `equals` that we would like it to do a case insensitive check (that's the second parameter).

Comment: great, thanks. I'll add toUppercase to manage all cases:   return this.toUpperCase() == "YES"

Comment: Sure, that way works as well. However, by calling `equals("yes", true)` you are telling `equals` to ignore the case when doing a comparison.

Comment: I find this is one case where it's helpful to specify the parameter name: `equals("yes", ignoreCase = true)`.  (And yes, no need for `this.` here.  In fact, I think the _only_ time you ever need it is to disambiguate from a param or local var with the same name.)

Answer (score 2):

Todd has the elegant solution but I have the **xtreme** one

```
val yeses = setOf("yes", "Yes", "yEs", "yeS", "YEs", "YeS", "yES", "YES")
fun String.toBoolean() = this in yeses
```

if you want **xtreme**ly moderate performance gains you might do something silly like this!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the simplest version of the **xtreme** with something like this (I noticed it was added as a comment above too).

```
fun String.toBoolean() = when (this.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())) {
    "YES" -> true
    else -> false
}
```